# Amount to make the game fair (expected value 0) with odds ratio given?

Tags: probability

Say your roommate says that she has a dog and will make you 10:1 odds if you can guess her dog's weight to within +/- a set amount. What set amount would you ask her for to make the game fair (expected value 0)?

My work
p/(1-p) = 10

p = 10(1-p)

p = 10 - 10p

11p = 10

p= 10/11

let the amount be x

E(X) = x *p + (1-p)(-x)

= x*10/11 + 1/11 (-x)

= 9x/11

hence x = 0
what is wrong here ? what is correct solution ?

Comment: How can one possibly answer this question?  What is the probability that you guess the dog's name?  (Maybe you already know the dog's name and your roommate is throwing her money away.)  Maybe in the country your roommate comes from, all dogs are named either Spot or Fido, with equal probability.  There has to be more information.

Comment: @saulspatz , dog's weight is to be estimated ,not name.